# How to resize image and create thumbnail in silvestripe 4.4

Tags: php, image, templates, url, resize

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

I want to create gallery with silvestripe 4.4

I created the model and template and I am able to get images throughout loop but could not resize images to create thumbnails for image

```
<?php

namespace SilverStripe\Lessons;

use SilverStripe\Forms\DateField;
use SilverStripe\Forms\TextareaField;
use SilverStripe\Forms\TextField;
use SilverStripe\Assets\Image;
use SilverStripe\Assets\File;
use SilverStripe\AssetAdmin\Forms\UploadField;
use Page;

class GalleryPage extends Page
{
    private static $table_name = 'GalleryPage';

    private static $can_be_root = false;

    private static $db = [
        'Date' => 'Date',
        'Author' => 'Varchar',
    ];

    private static $has_one = [
        'PhotoCover' => Image::class,
    ];

    private static $many_many = [
        'Gallery' => Image::class,
    ];

    private static $owns = [
        'PhotoCover',
        'Gallery',
    ];

    public function getCMSFields()
    {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', DateField::create('Date','Date of article'), 'Content');
        $fields->addFieldToTab(
            'Root.Main',
            $PhotoCover = UploadField::create('PhotoCover'), 'Author');
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', TextField::create('Author','Author of article'),'Content');


        $PhotoCover->setFolderName('PhotoCovers');


        $fields->addFieldToTab(
            'Root.Gallery',
            $Gallery = UploadField::create('Gallery')->setDescription('Selektuj Photos')
        );



        $Gallery->setFolderName('Gallery');

        return $fields;
    }

}
```

and here is my template GalleryPage.ss

```
<% if $Gallery %>
    <% loop $Gallery %>
     <a class="thumb" href="$URL" data-lightgallery="group-item">
        <img  src="$URL" alt="" width="371" height="276"/>
    </a>
    <% end_loop %>
<% end_if %>
```

This is the only way I can get images through loop
I tried options like:

```
<img class="my-custom-class" src="$Gallery.ScaleWidth(750).URL" alt="" width="$Gallery.ScaleWidth(750).Width" height="$Gallery.ScaleWidth(750).Height" />

or

<% with $Gallery.ScaleWidth(750) %>
    <img class="my-custom-class" src="$URL" alt="" width="$Width" height="$Height" />
<% end_with %>
```

All til now was unsuccessful trying olny...

What I`m doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

As per SS [documentation](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/templates/syntax/#me)

$Me outputs the current object in scope. This will call the forTemplate of the object.

In your case its '$Me.ScaleWidth(750).URL'

```
<% if $Gallery %>
    <% loop $Gallery %>
     <a class="thumb" href="{$Me.ScaleWidth(750).URL}" data-lightgallery="group-item">
        <img  src="$URL" alt="" width="371" height="276"/>
    </a>
    <% end_loop %>
<% end_if %>
```